# executeFetchRequest crashes app for NSPredicate with NSString object on left side of CONTAINS

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to fetch objects from Core Data whose **'name' attribute CONTAINS a specific NSString sPersonName**. Following code is doing that

```
NSString *sPersonName = @"Some Value";
NSFetchRequest<Entity*>* request = [Entity fetchRequest];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", sPersonName]];
NSError *error;
NSArray *arrResults = [self.persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

**this code executes fine** and I am getting results as expected.

But if I don't get any results from the upper request, I try to get objects from Core Data such that **sPersonName string CONTAINS value of 'name' attribute** of saved objects.
Below is the code for that.

```
request = [Entity fetchRequest];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] name", sPersonName]];
arrResults = [self.persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

This command **fails** and crashes the app creating following error

```
-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170a43750
2017-01-24 23:02:28.124224 TestApp[2934:845977] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170a43750'
```

Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
[screenshot of predicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0GBw.png)

Comment: Try `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] name", sPersonName];` and then set a breakpoint in the debugger and see if it looks ok there. edit: Actually you can just debug as is and look at request.predicate

Comment: but what does the predicate actually contain when you look at with the debugger? does it look right

Comment: I mentioned wrong predicate in last comment, had to delete that. Here is the actual one,

`request = [Entity fetchRequest];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] name", sIngred];
[request setPredicate:predicate];`
until this point, everything is fine. **I have also added a screenshot to the question too.**
but when I execute this request, it fails.
`arrResults = [self.m_persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after few days of trial and error, I found the solution.
**NSPredicate** expects a data structure object such as **NSArray** to be on the left side for CONTAINS. Passing a **NSString** object breaks it.

So, the solution was to covert NSString into NSArray. Below code runs fine.

```
NSArray *arrName = [sPersonName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] name", arrName];


[request setPredicate:predicate];
arrResults = [self.m_persistentContainer.viewContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```